# How to preload external website before redirecting user the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a landing page that should redirect a user to a different website (not a same domain website, and I have no control over the final website).

The final destination is loading very slowly, causing a massive drop-off of potential signups.

I want to show a loading animation on my website before redirecting the user - While the animation is on, I would preload/cache the external website, so it loads faster.

I tried using:

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="https://www.example.com/">
```

But I have no control over that and can't make the animation (plus, it didn't really speed up the load time of the final destination).

I also tried using the solution with hidden iframes - but that gets blocked due to 'X-Frame-Options'.

Is it even possible to do what I'm looking to do?

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you to redirect user with exact sign up page URL that would probably be more quicker, as often sign up forms are not much loaded like the home page

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no direct signup form as sign up is done trough the modal

Comment: Can you share the URL of that page ?